# Unable to run angular4 test cases

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I am getting an error (p.s. attached screenshot) when I run `ng test` in my angular4 app. I have not changed anything as such this just added some test specs in app.component.spec.ts

My `karma.config.js` file has following code

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
      require('angular-cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: {
        html: 'coverage',
        lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
      }
    },
    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul']
              : ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

error: 
[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

You are using a rather old version of @angular/cli (since it is still called `angular-cli` in your karma.conf.js file).

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7443) in older versions of @angular/cli.
To support the latest modules you might move to a newer version of @angular/cli:

`npm uninstall angular-cli -g
npm install @angular/cli -g`

Refer to [the update guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli) or the [update wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update) of @angular/cli to update your project.